# Passing ref from child to parent to anothe child in React

Tags: reactjs, reference, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to extract a reference from a child and make it available elsewhere in my app.  Here is my parent component:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

   setRef = (ref) => {
      this.mapReference = ref
      console.log(this.mapReference);
   }

   render () {
      return (
         <div className="App">
            <Map setRef={this.setRef} />
            <UIWindow mapRef={this.mapReference} />
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default App;
```

And the reference is coming from the callback `setRef` function in the `<Map />` component, which looks like this:

```js
class Map extends React.Component {


   componentDidMount(){
      this.props.setRef(this.refs.map.leafletElement)
   }

   render () {

      const { position, zoom } = this.props

      return(
         <LeafletMap
            className="sidebar-map" 
            center={position} zoom={zoom} id="mapId" 
            ref={"map"}
         >


         </LeafletMap>
      )
   }
}
```

The console.log statement in my `<App />` is returning my reference correctly, which is a map object.  So my reference is being correctly passed from the child (`<Map />`) to the parent (`<App />`), and is available there.  As you can see, I am trying to pass that reference back down into my `<UIWindow />` to have access to it there.

```js
class UIWindow extends React.Component {

   componentDidMount() {
      console.log(this.props.mapRef);
   }

   render () {
      return(
         <div className="UIWindow">
            <Header />
            <ControlLayer />
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default UIWindow;
```

But within my `UIWindow`, `this.props.mapRef` is undefined - the log statement is giving undefined. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  If its defined in the parent App, why is it undefined in the child?  Is this not the correct way to pass a reference between siblings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React does not know what `this.mapReference` is when it re-renders since the variable was tied to that instance of the class. You can declare state and pass it to the child:

```
class App extends React.Component {
   state = { mapReference: null }   

   setRef = ref => {
      this.setState({ mapReference: ref }, () =>
      console.log(this.state.mapReference)
     ); //Log once reference is updated
   };       

   render () {
      return (
         <div className="App">
            <Map setRef={this.setRef} />
            {this.state.mapReference && <UIWindow mapRef={this.state.mapReference} />}
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: this is still giving me a value of `null` when trying to access this.props.mapRef from within the `<UIWindow>` component.  Your code works to log the reference as a part of state from within the `App`.  I noticed that if I try to log it from the `UIWindow` from within a `componentDidMount`, it doesn't work, it returns null.  But if I log it from within a `componentDidUpate`, it does indeed work.  So `UIWindow` has to wait for the `setRef` function to run, update `App` state, and then pass it to `UIWindow`.  Is there no way to have this ref accessible from the moment `UIWindow` mounts?

Comment: Yes we can, see the edit! However, since we are mounting the component only when we have the reference, you have to adjust your UI with a loader or whatever you prefer.